# Create a nice Codename One slider to notify a percentage

Tags: codenameone

*Note for the readers: this question is specific for Codename One, it's not about css, html or similar.*

My use case is to notify the user how much his/her profile is complete.
I need to implement a slider like the following one, but after a lot of trials with the [Slider component](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Slider.html) I didn't understood how to implement it. *(Honestly I did not even understood how to start implementing it and I don't know if the Slider component is suitable.)*

The width of this slider should be equal to the contentPane of the parent Form. Basically it is a rectangle with a small border: one part of the rectangle is coloured, the other is white, according to the percentage. Over the rectangle I need the percentage and a text: percentage and text are in a fixed position. The colour of the text changes according to the background colour, as it's shown in the second image.

Thank you for any help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy except for the color change. That portion requires hand coding of the graphics. I didn't run this code but it should be pretty close to how this should work:

```
class ProgressSlider extends Component {
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(convert(getDisplayWidth(), 6));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(0xffffff);
         g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
         g.setColor(0);
         Font f = getStyle().getFont();
         g.drawString(progressPercetage, convert(4) + getX(), getY() + f.getHeight() / 2 + getHeight() - 2);
         g.drawString(progressText, convert(10) + getX(), getY() + f.getHeight() / 2 + getHeight() - 2);
         g.setColor(RED);
         g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() / 100 * progressPercentage, getHeight());
         g.setColor(0xcccccc);
         g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
         g.clipRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() / 100 * progressPercentage, getHeight());
         g.setColor(0xffffff);             
         g.drawString(progressPercetage, convert(4) + getX(), getY() + f.getHeight() / 2 + getHeight() - 2);
         g.drawString(progressText, convert(10) + getX(), getY() + f.getHeight() / 2 + getHeight() - 2);
    }
}
```

This might be missing a few details like resetting the clipping region etc. I didn't run it but it should produce pretty much that result when tuned correctly. The text is drawn twice (second time with clipping) to replicate the color change effect.

Comment: You gave me the right direction!!! Thank you very much! For the readers, I commented your code and inserted few fixes to make it working perfectly: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/4fe7e3679bbca4d1875f2c4ccfb9e7eb

Comment: Is there documentation about these hard-coded graphics functions? The API has few documentation, for example I didn't understood the `g.clipRect` from the API, even if I can guess how it works by this code.

Comment: There is the graphics section in the developer guide. It's modeled based on Java's AWT/Swing graphics conventions so should be very familiar to most developers. Internally all Codename One components are built on this API

Comment: I've done a first quick reading: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html It seems hard to learn (because I've never used the graphics at this level), however it allows things that normally are not possible with the standard Components. It can be very useful in special use cases.

Comment: Is `g.resetAffine();` important after a `g.clipRect` in this use case? Is that the method to reset the clipping region?

Comment: By convention you should return the graphics object in a similar state to the one you got it in. It's not always essential but sometimes code might inadvertently rely on that and you can end up with a weird bug that happens only in some conditions and some platforms. You can use `setClip()` instead of `resetAffine` which works on the affine transforms. For most use cases you don't need to touch the affine transform and don't need resetAffine as a result. A newer trick is to use `pushClip()` then `popClip()` when you are done, I haven't grown the habit of using it yet ;-)